# How do you make a signed & obfuscated android release build from inside eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

My android development process is to build and debug my app in eclipse and when I'm ready to publish I produce a signed, obfuscated (with proguard) apk by running "ant release" from the shell.

Is it possible to produce a signed, proguard release from within eclipse?  I'm using eclipse indigo  on windows with version 13 of the ADK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Once you enable ProGuard by adding the `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` entry to `project.properties`, Eclipse will obfuscate your code when you export an signed package. Details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html#enabling).

BTW, you should upgrade to the latest ADT (15).

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the ADT(15). But how do I tell if it worked / obfuscated? when I run ant release I can see proguard progress - in eclipse nothing.  I do get the apk file

Comment: Yes, there is no progress indicator or message. There is a message if you get an error though. If it worked there will be a 'progurad/' directory in your project dir, containing the usual files (mapping.txt, etc.).

Comment: I didn't get a proguard directory so I guess it isn't working then

Comment: Right, Got it working - upgrading to ADK 15 had mucked up my project and I couldn't build from ant anymore either. All fixed now.

Comment: Is there any setup for Dexguard in Eclipse IDE??@NikolayElenkov

Answer (score 0):

Use this in proguard files of yours you can able to make obfuscated build after enabling proguard in release/debug build.

```
Lakshay Proguard-Files entry details

# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.

-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontoptimize
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn com.loopj.android.http.**
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.**
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.**
#-injars      bin/classes
#-injars      libs
#-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar

# Using Google's License Verification Library
-keep class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Specifies to write out some more information during processing.
# If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.
-verbose

####################################################################################################
##############################  IBM MobileFirst Platform configuration  ############################
####################################################################################################
# Annotations are represented by attributes that have no direct effect on the execution of the code.
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}



-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}

# These options let obfuscated applications or libraries produce stack traces that can still be deciphered later on
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Enable proguard with Cordova
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin

-keep class com.worklight.androidgap.push.** { *; }
-keep class com.worklight.wlclient.push.** { *; }
-keep class com.worklight.common.security.AppAuthenticityToken { *; }

# Enable proguard with Google libs
-keep class com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

# apache.http
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class com.worklight.** {
    *;
}
-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** {
    *;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.**

-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.**
-optimizations !class/merging/vertical*,!class/merging/horizontal*,!code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!code/allocation/variable

-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.client.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.cookie.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.message.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.util.** { *; }

# These classes contain references to external jars which are not included in the default MobileFirst project.
-dontwarn com.worklight.common.internal.WLTrusteerInternal*
-dontwarn com.worklight.jsonstore.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.**
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.push.GCMIntentService
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.security.SecurityManager

-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.push.common.*
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush
-dontwarn com.worklight.wlclient.api.SecurityUtils
######################################################################################################
-ignorewarnings
```